# clicking on notification to launch activity (email) app fails

Tags: android, android-intent

The purpose of my app is to send an email at a predetermined time based on a schedule set with a broadcast receiver alarm using the users built in email configuration.  The **To:** and **Subject** are already filled out.  All the user has to do, is click on the notification when the alarm goes off, and it *should* prompt the user via an intent what email program to use via my SendMail.class.

If I call the class directly by dropping it into my "MainActivity onCreate it works.   If I place it in my Intent definition where I build my notification it never appears to get called.   This is the meat of my problem.  I need the intent create chooser to pop up with its list of valid email programs when the user clicks on the notification and its just not working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Coincidentally, I also have a preferences fragment to hold the settings of my app, and if I replace the call to SendMail.class to SetPreferenceActivity, then the notification works as expected (i.e. it successfully calls another class when the user clicks on it).

Here is the code for my notification manager method:

```
public void createNotification(View view) {

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String default_subject = mySharedPreferences.getString("default_subject", "");
    default_subject = default_subject + android.text.format.DateFormat.format("E MM-dd", new java.util.Date());

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SendMail.class);


    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Time to Send the Email")
            .setContentText("Date: "+default_subject)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

}
```

And here is what is going on in the SendMail.class

```
 public class SendMail extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sendMail();
}

public void sendMail() {

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto", "somebody@gmail.com", null));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Some Subject Text");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
 }
}
```

Here is the contents of my Manifest
    <.....snipped header>

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SetPreferenceActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="MintBootReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Which messages are shown in logcat when you click on the notification?

Comment: You need to add `SendMail` activity declaration to the manifest

Comment: David, your answer is correct.    I am using Android Studio and did a New->Class instead of New->Blank Activity.  When you add a new Class it does not get added into your manifest.  I don't know why I didn't see that as it was driving me nuts.   Thank you so much.  As soon as I figure out how to mark your answer as the correct one I will make sure you get the points.